# Parsing a JSON parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parameters

I must be missing something obvious - but

I have a controller.  One of the action recieves the following JSON parameter

```
Parameters: {"user_save_name"=>{"evaluation_assumption_id"=>"51"}, "id"=>"1"}
```

I want to assign the value associated with the evaluation_assumption_id e.g. in this case 51

Within the controller I can get the id parameter with the statement

```
@jsondata = params[:id]
```

which gives me 1

If use the following statement within the controller

```
@jsondata = params[:user_save_name]
```

I get {"evaluation_assumption_id"=>"51"} 
What I can't do is assign the value 51 to a variable.   How do I do this ?
Thanks in advance 
Pierre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`params[:user_save_name]` is a `Hash` itself so you can access the value as:

```
@jsondata = params[:user_save_name][:evaluation_assumption_id]
# => 51 (string)
```

This returns the value as string `"51"`. If you need to convert it to an integer use `to_i`

```
@jsondata = params[:user_save_name][:evaluation_assumption_id].to_i
# => 51 (integer)
```